# отлов всплывающих подсказок WinAPI

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Обычно, всплывающие подсказки реализуются посредством заполнения структуры NOTIFYICONDATA + передачей это структуры в функцию Shell_NotifyIconA. Если у экземпляра структуры NOTIFYICONDATA заполнить определённые параметры(не буду описывать подробно) то будет выдаваться всплывающая подсказка. Есть ли средства, дабы отловить показ таких подсказок? Желательно, ан уровне глобальных хуков. 
P.S.: может это облегчит задачу. Это требуется для win 10, а там все всплывающие подсказки == уведомления. Может к нему можно как-то обратиться.